# ps2pdf Unrecoverable error

Tags: unix, latex, ghostscript, postscript, ubuntu-11.10

I have an `unrecoverable error, exit code 1` showing up when I try to convert my .ps files to pdf. It worked just about a half hour ago and now it wont. The file is **there**!

```
Error: /undefinedfilename in (10132012a.ps)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1161/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.04: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Here is my command:

`ps2pdf 10132012a.ps 10132012b.pdf`

The ps file was created using `latex`.

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Can you use `pdflatex` to skip the `dvi`/`ps` steps?

Comment: @lhf Nope. I am using eps figures. Hence I need to use latex and NOT pdflatex

Comment: Try `dvipdfm` or `dvipdfmx` to skip the `dvips` step.

Comment: @lhf Will do so shortly! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You might try running Ghostscript directly, rather than using the script:

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o 10132012b.pdf 10132012a.ps

or even:

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o 10132012b.pdf - < 10132012a.ps

The "convenience" scripts (ps2pdf, pdf2ps, etc) use options which might get in the way (although they really shouldn't).

Comment: Sigh! This didn't work either. But thanks. I should look at my latex file and see if anything wonky is oing on.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a brilliant way to get this `/undefinedfilename` error. It took me about 15 minutes to figure it out.

First I did this.

```
user@host> dvips test1
This is dvips(k) 5.98 Copyright 2009 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2015.08.04:2315' -> test1.ps
</usr/lib/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro></usr/lib/texmf/dvips/base/texps.pro>. 
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>[-1] [-2] [1] [2]
```

And then I did this.

```
user@host> ps2pdf text1.ps
Error: /undefinedfilename in (text1.ps)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1172/3371(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:70/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Then it finally hit me. It was a spelling error in the file name. So the command line argument for `ps2pdf` was a non-existent file.

In my opinion, a better error message would be `Cannot find file test1.ps`, instead of `Error: /undefinedfilename in (text1.ps)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `ps2pdf` could not find the file `10132012a.ps`.

`latex` does not create ps files: it creates dvi files which can be converted to ps with `dvips`.

Perhaps you forgot to run `dvips`?

Comment: I did run `dvips` and found that 10132012a.ps was created.